# CodeIgniter : Create xml file and send it via FTP

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, ftp

I'm trying to create an XML file and tried to search on Google to see if there is a tutorial for me to follow on how to convert data to XML. I need to create the XML file itself and send it to my server using FTP.

```
$dom = xml_dom();
$lead = xml_add_child($dom, 'Leads');
    $leadData = xml_add_child($lead, 'LeadData');
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'CompanyName', $CompanyName);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'IndustryType', $IndustryType);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'ContactFirstName', $ContactFirstName);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'ContactLastName', $ContactLastName);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'ContactTitle', $ContactTitle);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'Phone', $Phone);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'Email', $Email);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'OpportunityAmount', $OpportunityAmount);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'LeadNotes', $LeadNotes);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'SalesRep', $SalesRep);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'Status', $Status);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'Category', $Category);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'Source', $Source);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'AnnualRevenue', $AnnualRevenue);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'BillingAddressLine1', $BillingAddressLine1);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'BillingAddressLine2', '');
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'BillingAddressLine3', '');
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'City', $City);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'State', $State);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'Zip', $Zip);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'BillingPhone', $BillingPhone);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'AppointmentDate', $AppointmentDate);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'AppointmentFromTime', $AppointmentFromTime);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'AppointmentToTime', $AppointmentToTime);
    xml_add_child($leadData, 'AppointmentDescription',$AppointmentDescription);
```

I believe that the code above is correct, right?

Comment: I cannot see the code where you try to send it to an FTP server. Please note that we need your code to be able to help you with it. We are not here to write your code for you...

Comment: @arkascha yes, the codes above is just for converting the data in xml format, what I'm asking is how to generate the converted data to .xml

Comment: You mean how to save it to a file? Well, use php's file operation functions, I'd say...

Comment: Or the file handling methods implemented in the class you already use, that is. In this case: http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php

Comment: is it safe to use those methods with codeigniter?.

Comment: Your code above has nothing to do with that framework, so why should handling the data you produce having anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use codeigniter to do this. Codeigniter is a framework to make PHP coding easier/better, but you are still programming in PHP.  Just read the documentation on the PHP website.
The steps are:

- create a dom and convert it to xml http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php
- save the file http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
- send the file to the FTP site:   http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php
- delete the temporary file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

remember when creating files on a website that you need to consider if the operation can occur more than once at the same time.  a way around this is to create a unique temporary directory to work from so there is no chance that two concurrent operations can conflict.

Taking a step back, i would question why you are sending this as a file, and not running a RESTful server that can accept POST data.  If you want more information on a codeigniter implementation of REST, have a look at this link https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver.